Utilize multiprocessing in Python with functions that do not return any value
Consider the following codes in Python:
from multiprocessing import Pool
data = [4] * 10

def update(j):
    data[j] += j ** 2

def solver():
    with Pool(8) as po:
        po.map(update, range(10))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    solver()

The result is that data list is not updated. I wish to find a safe way to update data in this manner using multiprocessing.
How to solve it in an elegant way?

Right.  Unlike with threads, each process has its own memory space, completely separate from all other processes.  The multiprocessing unit does have types that can be shared, but they get transferred between the processes through socket calls.

You tagged shared-memory. Did you try that?

One way to share a list between subprocesses is with Shared Memory. However, it's not particularly straightforward.
Here's what you could do using a ShareableList:
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import ShareableList

def process(j):
    global lock, data
    with lock:
        data[j] += j ** 2

def init_lock(lock_, data_):
    global lock, data
    lock = lock_
    data = data_

def main():
    lock = Lock()
    data = ShareableList([4]*10)
    try:
        with Pool(initializer=init_lock, initargs=(lock, data)) as pool:
            pool.map(process, range(10))
        print(*data)
    finally:
        data.shm.close()
        data.shm.unlink()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
4 5 8 13 20 29 40 53 68 85

EDIT:
It's rather surprising / disappointing that the ShareableList isn't context managed when it's clearly very important to clean it up properly after use. My original answer does clean up but maybe this is a better (more Pythonic?) approach:
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import ShareableList
from contextlib import contextmanager

N = 10

@contextmanager
def cmsl(*args, **kwargs):
    sl = ShareableList(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield sl
    finally:
        sl.shm.close()
        sl.shm.unlink()

def process(j):
    global lock, data
    with lock:
        data[j] += j**2

def init_proc(*args):
    global data, lock
    data, lock = args

def main():
    with cmsl([4] * N) as data:
        args = data, Lock()
        with Pool(None, init_proc, args) as pool:
            pool.map(process, range(N))
        print(*data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


@moooeeeep It's the lock that ensures exclusive access

@moooeeeep The question is about multiprocessing

@moooeeeep How about you contribute an answer rather than criticising others' attempts?

For once, chatgpt got it exactly right.  Data structures are not copied between processes.
Try:
def update(j):
    return j, j ** 2


def solver():
    with Pool(8) as po:
        for j, result in po.imap_unordered(update, range(10)):
           data[j] = result

You are letting the multiprocessing do the work of calculating the results in the worker processes of the Pool, but the actual updating of the data structure is all on your main process.

Answering question in comments below:
pool.map() doesn't return until all results are ready. Hence the creation of the data structure at the end will be O(n
pool.imap_unordered() returns each result as it becomes available, so your main thread can work in parallel with the processes. But it is up to you to know which result corresponds to which process.
In between is pool.imap().  It returns results in order as they become available.  It can't return the nth result until all the results 0..n-1 have been returned, but it won't wait for the later results.
Note that you don't really have to modify update.  What is more common is to write:
def update_helper(i):
    return i, update(i)

and then pass update_helper to your mapping function.

Thanks. It works. But imagine I do this:
with Pool(8) as po:
update_ls = po.map(update, range(10)) and then I manually add update_ls to data. There is an O(N) operation at the tail to add update to the data. Depending on how complicated the update function is, the actual speed up would differ. Is the pool.imap_unordered() faster (more optimized) in terms of the final O(N) operation so that you did not choose the approach I mentioned?

Answered in main text.
